# How to download csv ata from website using Python

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to automatically download data from the following website; however I just get the html and no data:
http://tcplus.com/GTN/OperationalCapacity#filter.GasDay=02/02/19&filter.CycleType=1&page=1&sort=LocationName&sort_direction=ascending

```
import csv
import urllib2

downloaded_data  = urllib2.urlopen('http://tcplus.com/GTN/OperationalCapacity#filter.GasDay=02/02/19&filter.CycleType=1&page=1&sort=LocationName&sort_direction=ascending')
csv_data = csv.reader(downloaded_data)

for row in csv_data:
    print row
```

Comment: The site is a nice and modern site using Javascript, and because of that is hard to automate. You must either figure out what the JavaScript is doing, or  use your browser developer tools to see exactly what requests are sent by the browser and emulate that in your Python code. It may be (rather) simple or not at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will only fetch data from provided url, but if you tweak parameters you can get other reports as well.

```
import requests

parameters = {'serviceTypeName': 'Ganesha.InfoPost.Service.OperationalCapacity.OperationalCapacityService, Ganesha.InfoPost.Service',
             'filterTypeName': 'Ganesha.InfoPost.ViewModels.GasDayAndCycleTypeFilterViewModel, Ganesha.InfoPost',
             'templateType': 6,
             'exportType': 1,
             'filter.GasDay': '02/02/19',
             'filter.CycleType': 1}

response = requests.post('http://tcplus.com/GTN/Export/Generate', data=parameters)

with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, how did you figure those parameters out?

Comment: @Mary You can open network panel in Chrome DevTools and filter requests by type Doc, then click on download csv button. You will see that POST request has been sent with those values.